# How do I view my friends' world records?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

I'd like to attempt to beat my friends' world records.  I can view my own in my creator profile, but I can't figure out how to view their profiles.

**How can I find their world records so I can destroy them?**

Answer (score 2):

You do it like every other maker, you go to their maker account and press the button that has a flag pole and a clock, if you press it it will bring the levels that your friend got a world record on.